# Must every XML file/stream/etc begin with either a "<" character, or with a BOM followed by a "<" character?

Tags: xml, file-format

I'm doing some filetype detection stuff and wanted to handle XML detection more robustly.

I added support for an optional initial Unicode BOM (Byte Order Mark) followed by a `<` character in either 8-bit or UTF-16 encoding.

(This is just an initial test. If this test passes then I proceed to try parsing it as XML, but I don't do that unless it looks like XML since it's more resource heavy.)

I looked at the XML standard but the jargon was getting quite think and I'm not sure I followed all the grammar rules properly, especially for the more esoteric features of XML. I didn't see anything specific in the standard about what characters it can start with though.

In particular, I'm not sure whether or not it's legal for XML files or streams to commence with whitespace fore the first `<`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A document entity must always start with "<", but if there's no XML declaration then this can be preceded by whitespace.

An external parsed entity doesn't require an initial "<". External parsed entities are not normally parsed on their own, only when referenced directly or indirectly from an entity reference in a document entity.

The spec isn't actually that complicated.

```
[1]     document       ::=      prolog element Misc*

[22]    prolog     ::=      XMLDecl? Misc* (doctypedecl Misc*)?
[23]    XMLDecl    ::=      '<?xml' VersionInfo EncodingDecl? SDDecl? S? '?>'

[27]    Misc       ::=      Comment | PI | S

[3]     S      ::=      (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
```

makes it pretty clear that if the XMLDecl is absent, then the document can start with Misc, which includes the option of whitespace. However, `XMLDecl`, `doctypedecl`, `element`, `Comment`, and `PI` all start with "`<`".

Comment: Ah OK I did read the spec right then. I doubted my reading because I'm sure I'd read in the past people saying that `<` as the first character was the one thing you can count on. But I didn't trust that either. Thanks!